# Combining Between and Like

Tags: sql, between, sql-like

Im trying to sort through a creditcard data base where the values are shown are

```
1564861254404000
```

And im and looking for all values that end between `4000 - 4050`

This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT * from GiftCard 
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, CardNumber, 2400)cardnumber BETWEEN  '%4000' AND '%4050'
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

How about using [RIGHT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177532.aspx) function?

```
SELECT * from GiftCard WHERE CAST(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CardNumber, 2400), 4) AS INT) cardnumber BETWEEN 4000 AND 4050
```

Answer (score 1):

If the CardNumber is a number you can use the remainder of the division by 10000

```
SELECT *
FROM   GiftCard
WHERE  MOD(CardNumber, 10000) Between 4000 AND 4050
```